# Two backgrounds on css style possible?

Tags: html, css

i have a web page using a css style file who have this property:

```
body { 
   background: #7a9c12 url(images/main_background.jpg) top center no-repeat; 
   color: #bbb;
   font: 12px/14px helvetica, arial,Sans-serif; 
}
```

As you can see this code only puts a background image on the top center on the div body. But, i need a background image in the botton center too of the body tag, how can i do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option if you're not using CSS3 is to layer the background images on your `html` and `body` tags:

```
html {
   background: #7a9c12 url(images/main_background_top.jpg) top center no-repeat;
}

body {
   background: url(images/main_background_bottom.jpg) bottom center no-repeat;
}
```

Just make sure you only apply a solid background colour to the `html` background property, otherwise you'll overlay the image and only see the `body` background image.

Answer (score 1):

With CSS3, you can have multiple backgrounds, separated by commas. See the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering). e.g.

```
background: url(banner.png) top center no-repeat, 
            url(footer.png) bottom center no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

With CSS2.1, no, it's impossible.
With CSS3, yes, you can.

> The background of a box can have
>   multiple layers in CSS3. The number of
>   layers is determined by the number of
>   comma-separated values in the
>   ‘background-image’ property.

Reference: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering).